# prevent default on ng2-bootstrap tab select angular2

Tags: angular, tabs, preventdefault, ng2-bootstrap

I have a set of tabs with each tab listing few items. I want to make sure that the user gets a warning when he has selected some stuff in one tab and tries to move to another. So I want a warning to popup before the selected tab becomes active. I'm currently using ng2-bootstrap tabs. I want to supress the select event and not let the newly selected tab become active before the user acts on the warning.

TIA!

Comment: Do you mean `ngx-bootstrap`?

Comment: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/examples

Answer (score 1):

You can declare custom header and use `event.stopPropagation` to supress the select event

**template.html**

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading='Tab 1'>Tab 1 content</tab>
  <tab>
    <template tabHeading>
      <div (click)="tryToSwitch($event)">
        Tab 2
      </div>
    </template>
    Tab 2 content
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

**component.ts**

```
tryToSwitch(e) {
  let result = confirm('Are you sure?');
  if(!result) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/fgyd1V7ub64fZpHkfxij?p=preview)**

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem completely. I should be able to handle click anywhere on the tab header, not just the heading text.

Comment: Consider your own plunkr. Click on the area around the 'Tab 2' text (In the tab header area). It doesn't prevent the event from happening.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/rr1j5EBZQVLkAXRQSbF0?p=preview I added custom class to this tab and applied some styles